# .htaccess remove the page and leave the query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change

http://example/index.php?name=phone

to

http://example/phone

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?name=$1
```

It actually allows me to use `example/phone` but it's not forcing a redirect when I use `example/index.php?name=phone`
I want to be able only to get to the clean url. When I write the non-clean url it should redirect me to the clean url.

Edit

i'll try to simplify the question . 
what i want is 
when i write

example/index.php?name=phone

it redirects me to

example/phone

and of course , 'phone' is a variable .

Comment: To "resolve" the question, please post an answer and/or accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?name=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?name=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go :

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tell your hosting sercvie to activate Re-Write capability of your service . maybe it's off

Comment: it's on , tried on different hosts . 
the strange thing is it works with some queries and other not !!
Any ideas of whats going on ?

Comment: @moawaya Do you have any rewrite rules prior to this one? If so, they might be affecting it.